# Kali Linux dual boot or tools in Linux Mint

Tags: multi-boot, linux-mint, kali-linux

I want to learn to use Kali Linux. I don't know what would be more practical Having the Kali Linux tools in Linux Mint using Katoolin or making a dual boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using Dual boot and not change your mint Linux , Kali Linux is not just a tools ' it's Also Configure as a Pen-test OS ,Many software can correct your original OS , it's better install Kali out of your original OS
also I using suggest install kali on the VMware or virtual box and use it